# Using Google maps Javascript API the good way

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps

I am trying to follow the practice of compiling all my javascript files and js plugins etc into one single javascript file, which then gets included into my website. So far I have been using gulp with npm for this purpose, but I am really struggling when it comes to the point that the libraries I want to include don't work like that. For example Google Maps API. So, how can I deal with such cases ? I have been asking around and I hear that there is not a way to "include" a javascript file like you can include a php file, but is this the final answer ?

I know you can include other files with jQuery on runtime, but that way you are not avoiding the additional http calls, remember the ideal case is to call one javascript file which has all the js code you need.

Even when I am using `require` in javascript, the required file must have a proper format and I have to assign it to a variable bla bla bla, but when I include a script like this `<script type="text/javascript" src="myjsfile.js"></script>` everything is included in my scope properly.

How can I work around this ? Would it be a good practice if a javascript compiler like gulp copied the contents of all my javascript source files and pasted them into one single merged file ? Wouldn't that work the same way as calling all those files with  ?

Well, I started this question because I am having troubles with the google maps api, but the problem is more general, so if you can help me please answer the above questions too. Anyway in the google maps api case, I am working with it perfectly fine when I include it like this

```
<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&callback=Mycallback">
</script>
```

But how can I merge this into my minified way of including libraries ? I tried to use some npm libraries that integrate with google maps api (like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googlemaps) for example), but I am getting CORS problems and I think this is an expected behaviour.

Thanks in advance ! Sorry if something sounds stupid, I am trying to learn the good way of coding.

Comment: Google Maps JavaScript API must be loaded from Google servers, otherwise it won't work as expected. You shouldn't merge it into your local js file.

Answer (score 0):

Decent question.

I'm not an expert but there is my subquestion/answer:

`async` attribute lets load html and script(s) simultaneously. If map is main feature of site, I would place `<script>` on top of loading html file so its not always rule to place in to the bottom of `<body>`.